# Winter Hats 2015 - Do they go away after the Holidays?

Tags: discussion

I think January 3rd is when the Winter Hat Bash is over.

I was wondering, do the hats go away from our profiles on that date?  I dug around meta and couldn't find the answer (not that it isn't there)

Just curious.

Cheers!

Comment: See this [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/01/winter-bash-2015-hats-off/?cb=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. IIRC, they last through about the first week of January. So ... hats go byebye when the Winter Bash is over. If it's the 3rd, then figure Sunday evening at rollover.

Comment: Even the secret hats?  I was under the impression secret hats were for life.  Or is it just the Winter Bash secret hats that go away?

Comment: As far as I know. This is my third Winter Bash ... they always go away.

Comment: Bummer.  I have 23 hats.  I want to keep them.  All of them....lol

Comment: Wow, don't get out much, do you? ;-)

Comment: Only to rip wheelies on the freeway late at night